# React Store does not return getMethod's value first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mobx, mobx-react

I am new to React, Mobx stack. I bumped into a problem where my Store does not reflect its value immediately after the first call. when I make the second call, it returns the first value. I am unable to understand why it happens since I have a long way to go in React, Mobx stack.

**My Store Class**

```
export default class ServiceTemplateStore {

    loadingInitial = false;

    serviceTemplateDetail: any | undefined;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }

    setLoadingInitial = (state: boolean) => {
        this.loadingInitial = state;
    }


    get getServiceTemplateDetail() {
        return this.serviceTemplateDetail;
    }

    
    loadServiceTemplateDetail = async (id: string) => {
        this.loadingInitial = true;

        try {

            const serviceTemplateDetail = await agent.serviceTemplateDetail.details(id);

            runInAction(() => {
                console.log("Service loaded");
                this.serviceTemplateDetail = serviceTemplateDetail;
                console.log(this.serviceTemplateDetail); //Here I can see it immediately outputs the value.
                this.setLoadingInitial(false);
            });
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            this.setLoadingInitial(false);
        }
    }

}
```

**Child component**

Here is where I am using the Store, when I use the `useEffect` Hook it actually populates the data, but when I run in inside `onClick` function it does not populate the value.

What my understanding is that Axios `GET` call executes as expected, also it returns the value back and assigns it to `serviceTemplateDetail` variable. but when I am accessing the value via `getServiceTemplateDetail` method it returns null for the first time, and when I click the Import Button next time it returns the old value which was returned from `GET` Request

```
import DataGrid, { Selection } from "devextreme-react/data-grid";
import Popup, { Position, ToolbarItem } from "devextreme-react/popup";
import { Column } from "devextreme-react/tree-list";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import React, { Component, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useStore } from "../store/Store";


export default observer(function ImportServiceTemplate(props: importServiceProp) {

    const [ serviceTemplateIds, setServiceTemplateIds] = useState([]);
    const { serviceTemplateStore } = useStore();
    const { serviceTemplateList, loadServiceTemplateList, loadServiceTemplateDetail, getServiceTemplateDetail, serviceTemplateDetail } = serviceTemplateStore;
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (serviceTemplateList?.length === 0 || serviceTemplateList === undefined) loadServiceTemplateList();
    }, [loadServiceTemplateList])


    const closeButtonOption = {
        icon: 'close',
        text: 'Close',
        onClick: ()=>{
            props.onCloseImportModel();
        }
    };

    //Added a useEffect to test..
    //UseEffect returns the value but not my Import function below
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("use effect");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(getServiceTemplateDetail));
    }, [getServiceTemplateDetail])
    

    //Actual function that needs to work.
    const importButtonOption = {
        icon: 'download',
        text: 'Import',
        onClick: () => {

            if(serviceTemplateIds){

                loadServiceTemplateDetail(String(serviceTemplateIds))
                .then(()=>{
                    console.log("Callback");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(serviceTemplateDetail));     // Getting undefined as output.
                    props.importingServiceTemplate(getServiceTemplateDetail); //Passing the imported value to parent component
                });

            }
            
        }
    };

    const onSelectionChanged = (e: any) => {
        console.log("Processing", e.selectedRowKeys);
        setServiceTemplateIds(e.selectedRowKeys);
    };

    return (
        <>

            <Popup
                visible={props.isImportVisible}
                dragEnabled={false}
                closeOnOutsideClick={false}
                showCloseButton={false}
                showTitle={true}
                title="Service Template"
                width={800}
                height={280}>
                <Position
                    at="center"
                    my="center"
                />

                <DataGrid
                    id="serviceTemplateGrid"
                    key="ServiceTemplateId"
                    keyExpr="ServiceTemplateId"
                    focusedRowEnabled={true}
                    onSelectionChanged={onSelectionChanged}
                    selectedRowKeys={serviceTemplateIds}
                    dataSource={serviceTemplateList}
                    showRowLines={true}
                    showBorders={true}>

                    <Selection mode="multiple" showCheckBoxesMode="onClick" />
                    <Column dataField="Name" caption="Name" />
                    <Column dataField="CustomerName" caption="Customer Name" />
                    <Column dataField="BaseCurrencyCode" caption="Currency" />
                    <Column dataField="Description" caption="Description" />

                </DataGrid>
    
                <ToolbarItem
                    widget="dxButton"
                    toolbar="bottom"
                    location="before"
                    options={closeButtonOption}
                />

                <ToolbarItem
                    widget="dxButton"
                    toolbar="bottom"
                    location="after"
                    options={importButtonOption}
                />
                
                <div>{JSON.stringify(getServiceTemplateDetail)}</div>

            </Popup>
        </>
    )

})

interface importServiceProp{
    isImportVisible: boolean;
    onCloseImportModel: Function
    importingServiceTemplate: any
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not React or MobX problem, just a regular javascript closure.

When you create `importButtonOption` function it `remembers` all the variables around it, and `serviceTemplateDetail` is equals undefined at first time. So after you invoke `loadServiceTemplateDetail` `serviceTemplateDetail` is changed in the store, but inside `importButtonOption` function it is still an old value which was `remembered` when the function was created.

Hope it makes sense. Basically you just need to read about closures and how they work.

There is a little guide in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

What you can do for example is remove destructuring of values and dereference them as you need, like that:

```
loadServiceTemplateDetail(String(serviceTemplateIds))
  .then(()=>{
      console.log("Callback");
      console.log(JSON.stringify(serviceTemplateStore .serviceTemplateDetail));     // reference it from the store to get actual value
      props.importingServiceTemplate(getServiceTemplateDetail); //Passing the imported value to parent component
  });
```

Comment: You are correct. Also I have another doubt. in `props.importingServiceTemplate(serviceTemplateStore.getServiceTemplateDetail);` serviceTemplateStore is also created as a Store variable. How does this not hold the old value?

Comment: In simpler terms because `serviceTemplateStore` is not a primitive value, it is an object and when you assign object to a variable you are actually assigning "reference" to a "live" object and it is always "up to date".